# Get last inserted message from kafka topic

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a requirement where I need to find the recently inserted message from Kafka topic. How can I achieve this?

I tried to fetch offset first and trying to get messages from that offset?
Is it efficient solution?

```
val config = KafkaConfig()
  val props = new Properties()
//  ConsumerConfig
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", config.bootstrapServers)
  props.put("group.id", "stream-latest-consumer")
  props.put(
    "key.deserializer",
    "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
  )
  props.put(
    "value.deserializer",
    "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
  )
  val kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)

  val p = new TopicPartition(config.topic, 0)
  val cl: util.Collection[TopicPartition] = List(p).asJava
  val offsetsMap: java.util.Map[TopicPartition, java.lang.Long] =
    kafkaConsumer.endOffsets(cl)

  val offsetCount = offsetsMap.get(p)
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried and why you think that is bad solution or don't work. We need this info in order to help you. For example, if you are using Java to write your consumer there is simple solution how to retrieve latest offset for topic and after that query broker from custom offset.

Comment: You always get the latest offset messages from Apache Kafka topics using consumers unless you explicitly define offset for consumption. Show us what you have accomplished posting snippets of your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use

```
void seekToEnd(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)
```

in order to get the latest offset for the given partitions.